# Some bones don't move in pose mode

Tags: rigging, bones, pose-mode

Some bones wont move when I'm in pose mode. For example the head, the neck and the upper spike move without a problem. But when I try to move the eyes and the other spikes only the bones move not the mech. I've parented them all to the head. And did the weight painting myself. Does anyone know what may be wrong?[image]

Comment: Hmm if you did the weight painting correctly, and the names are right, and the [Deform] is checked in the settings panel, I can't really imagine what reason could be that it doesn't work. This is a bit too little information to say more. maybe submit your blend file using Bend-Exchange...

Comment: Thank you I will check if deform is checked tomorrow. I hope it will help with the problem.